# Grails comparing a list within a list in a gsp

Tags: list, grails, conditional-statements, scaffolding

I have a one-to-many relationship table where I am grabbing a list of members by a committee id.  When the output is displayed I get the correct amount of members but the corresponding committee position type is being displayed as a list and not the individual position for that committee.
So I came up with the idea of comparing the committee position list with a param that I pass.

When I put in the if tag, nothing is displayed.  When I remote the tag, I can see the output of my list and the param that I am pasting into it.  I have used == and .equals() but get that same output of nothing.

What an I missing?

Legacy DB Using Oracle 11g, and Grails 2.3.3
 [image]
Here is an example of my list within a list.
Here is my GSP code

```
<thead>
    <tr class="revheaddark-c">
        <!-- display all of the current members information -->
        <th width="33%" class="revheaddark-t"><g:message code="trustee.lastName.label" default="Name" /></th>
        <th width="33%" class="revheaddark-t"><g:message code="trustee.committees.label" default="Officers of the Board" /></th>
        <th width="33%" class="revheaddark-t"><g:message code="trustee.hospital.label" default="Trustee Membership" /></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<g:each in="${trusteeInstanceList}" status="i" var="trusteeInstance">
<tr class="${i % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'cellshade'}">
    <td><g:link action="contactInfo" params="[contactId:'${trusteeInstance.id}']" id="${trusteeInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: trusteeInstance, field: "salutation")}${fieldValue(bean: trusteeInstance, field: "firstName")} ${fieldValue(bean: trusteeInstance, field: "middleName")} ${fieldValue(bean: trusteeInstance, field: "lastName")}</g:link></td>
enter code here
    <td><g:each in="${trusteeInstance.membership}">
            <g:if test="${it.committees.id == params.committee }">
        <%--<tr><td>--%>
                ${params.committee }, ${it.position }, ${it.committees.id }
        <%--</td></tr>--%>
            </g:if>

    <td><g:each in="${trusteeInstance.board}">
    <g:if test="${it.boardName.next() == null}">${it.boardName} </g:if>
    <g:else>${it.boardName}, </g:else>
    </g:each></td>

</tr>
</g:each>
```

Here is my controller

```
def members(){
   params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max'): 15, 100)

   def listCommittees = Committees.findAll("from Committees as c where c.hospital.id = '1'")

   def indexSearch = Trustee.withCriteria(){

      //search by First letter of lastName
      if(params.letter){
         ilike("lastName", "${params.letter}%")
      }

      //search by lastName
      if(params.lastName){
         ilike("lastName", "%${params.lastName}%")
      }

      //search by firstName
      if(params.firstName){
         ilike("firstName", "%${params.firstName}%")
      }

      //search by hospitalName
//      if(params.hospital){
//         board{
//            eq "hospital.id", params.long('hospital')
//         }
//      }

      //search by committeeId
      if(params.committee){
         //display only members will the board id
         membership{
            eq "committees.id", params.long('committee')
         }
      }

      //search by Type
      if(params.mType){
         membership{
            eq("memberType", "${params.mType}")
         }
      }

      //search by boardName
      if(params.boardId){
         //display only members with the boardName
         board{
            eq("id", params.long('boardId'))
         }
      }

      like("is_Trustee","Y")
      order("lastName", "asc")
   }

   //def memberTrustee = TrusteeMembership.findAll("from TrusteeMembership as tm where tm.committee.id = 'params.committee'")

   respond Hospitals.list(params), model:[hospitalsInstanceCount: Hospitals.count(),
   trusteeInstanceList : indexSearch,
   //memberList: memberTrustee,
   sideMenu: Hospitals.list(max:1, order:"desc")]
}
```

Here are the domains.

```
class TrusteeMembership implements Serializable{

   String position
   String memberType

   static belongsTo = [trustee:Trustee, committees:Committees]//

   static constraints = {
      position nullable:true
      memberType nullable:true, unique:true
   }

   static mapping = {
      table 'BOT_TRUSTEE_COMMITTEES'
      version false
      id composite: ['trustee','committees']
      trustee column:'TRUSTEE_ID'
      committees column: 'COMMITTEE_ID'

      position column:'POSITION'
      memberType column:'TYPE'
   }

package trusteedbtest

class Trustee {

   String salutation
   String firstName
   String middleName
   String lastName

   static hasMany = [board:Boards, membership:TrusteeMembership]

   static constraints = {
      salutation nullable: true
      firstName nullable: true
      middleName nullable: true
      lastName nullable: true
   }

   //map to the existing DB table
   static mapping = {
      table 'BOT_TRUSTEE'
      id column:'TRUSTEE_ID'
      salutation column: 'SALUTATION'
      firstName column: 'FIRST_NAME'
      middleName column: 'MIDDLE_INITIAL'
      lastName column: 'LAST_NAME'
   }
}
```